# Karma.js: Does anyone know how to make karma return filename of logging / errors

Tags: javascript, tdd, stack-trace, karma-runner

I'm using requirejs for a not super complicated project- problem is that I have some utility methods that log information to console and it's brought to my attention a question I've had for a while but never asked:

#### Say you have karma running unit tests on roughly a few billion files and one of them is logging to the console...

**Without using a stack trace**, how can you determine the name / location of that ONE file?

or

**What would be  the easiest way to filter / refine / define karma's output** (other than adjusting logLevel)?

I've looked into different reporters, and will be trying to write one for karma here soon, I'm just trying to make sure I know what's available (if applicable).

### karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set ({
        basePath      : '../',
        frameworks    : ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai'],
        files         : [
            {pattern: 'tests/_*.js', included: false},
            'tests/test-main.js'
        ],
        reporters     : ['dots', 'growl'],
        port          : 9876,
        logLevel      : config.LOG_DEBUG,
        //autoWatch     : true,
        autoWatch     : false,
        plugins       : [
            'karma-requirejs',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-chai',
        ],
        singleRun     : false
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using mocha: I would suggest to have more a "test-title" approach rather than a "filename" one.

What about a solution like the following - it could be implemented in karma as well with a custom reporter:

```
afterEach(function(){
    // use here a global variable or
    // appending it as property on the runner
    if(variableToLookAt){
      console.log(this.currentTest.fullTitle() + ': '+your_message_here);
    }
});
```

The snippet above can be insert inside a `describe` suite block, or better in case of nested suites, in every block that contains a test (`it`).